# build mysql query for the right result: find string prepend by some dash

Tags: php, mysql, regex

i have records item_name. each item_name has long name split by 11 dashes (-). i use 10 select form to filter data in search form. i passed select form if the column is empty. user may select multiple option in it. i have a problem when user choose "S" and "I" in 9th select form. because it will messed with other record ended with s in other part.

i have tried to query like this:

```
select item_name from table_name where (item_name like '%S-%')
```

===== data sample =====

1. Suspeno-Fazalqe-ST-Jig-Baroque-Chop Plate 12"--2118 Bloom-Gloss-Royal Of London-I-2118 Bloom
2. Fazalqe-ST-Jig-Baroque-Cup--Maroon-‪#‎Gloss‬-Royal Of London-S-2118 Bloom
3. Fazalqe-ST-Jig-Baroque-Saucer 6.5--Maroon-#Gloss-Royal Of London-S-2118 Bloom
4. Suspeno-Fazal BS-ST-Jig-Baroque-Soup Plate--2118 Bloom-Gloss-Royal Of London-I-2118 Bloom
5. Suspeno-Fazal-ST-Jig-Baroque-Salad Plate 7.25--2118 Bloom-Gloss-Royal Of London-S-2118 Bloom
6. Fazalqe-ST-Cas-Baroque-Creamer--Brown Orchid-#Gloss-Royal Of London-I-2139 Bloom Brown
7. Fazalqe-ST-Cas-Baroque-Sugar Lid---#Gloss--I-2139 Bloom Brown
8. Fazalqe-ST-Cas-Baroque-Sugar--Brown Orchid-#Gloss-Royal Of London-I-2139 Bloom Brown
9. Fazalqe-ST-Cas-Baroque-Teapot--Brown Orchid-#Gloss-Royal Of London-I-2139 Bloom Brown

i think maybe i need regexp, but i don't have enough skill in it. i just thinking if i can query using wildcards like this

```
select item_name from table_name where item_name like "*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-(S-)*"
```

the right result should be row number 2,3 and 5.
somebody can help me to realize that. thank you before.

Comment: You need a regexp. There are plenty of tutorials that will help you learn. It's a useful skill to develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to improve wildcards query above,

```
"*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-(S-)*"
```

maybe you could try to write this:

```
'.*\-.*\-.*\-.*\-.*\-.*\-.*\-.*\-.*\-S\-.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this,
select item_name from table_name where (item_name like '%-S-%')

Comment: i can't use - (dash) before S, because S comes from option value from variable post.

Comment: thx harsh1802, but i can't simply use - (dash) before S, because S comes from option value from variable post. i have create query string builder with php to accommodate multiple option sent by POST. like:
`AND (item_name LIKE '%S-%' OR item_name LIKE '%I-%')`

Comment: sorry, but I am not getting your point. u can still use Like: item_name LIKE '%S-%' OR item_name LIKE '%I-%'.
you also want a records with some charactors before S..Like : XYZS-%?

Comment: as I mentioned at the beginning, that I had 11 select input form that is multiple choice. on select form from 1 to 9 also have the option value that can be inserted into the query. So, the query 'S' is a MUST occur after 9 dash before.